# Какова этимология выражения "лепить горбатого"?

Tags: фразеология, жаргон

Я прочитала в Сети некоторые версии, но мне они показались **надуманными**. Если дословно рассматривать это сочетание, то я рассуждала  бы так.

Если ты занимаешься творчеством (сочиняешь, рисуешь, лепишь скульптуры), то  делай это качественно, **то есть не лепи горбатого**, а правильно передавай пропорции тела.

И еще **о значении** словосочетания: оно означает "не обманывай" или "не обманывай так неправдоподобно"?

И наконец,  последний вопрос: **когда и в каких источниках это жаргонное выражение появилось впервые?**

Comment: Версий много, но ни одна их них не имеет прямого доказательства, все они напоминают фантазии на тему. Я привела свое  рассуждение не для того, чтобы решить вопрос,  а чтобы, наоборот, поставить его. Мне интересно, что было сначала: просто лепить горбатого или лепить горбатого к стенке (если рассматривать эту версию).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Слово *лепить* присутствует в блатном варгоне и обозначает "придумывать, привирать" ([http://www.вокабула.рф/%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8/%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%B6%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BD/%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C](http://www.%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%BB%D0%B0.%D1%80%D1%84/%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8/%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%B6%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BD/%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C))

Думаю, "лепить горбатого" — делать это неумело (результат "горбатый").

Вот нечто подобное нашлось в сети:

ГОРБАТОГО ЛЕПИТ К СТЕНКЕ - неумело, неубедительно вpать ([Словарь "воровского жаргона"](http://www.biometrica.tomsk.ru/ftp/dict/slang/jargon.htm))

Comment: Часто встречается  "лепить горбатого к стенке", но я  не уверена, что это не позднее добавление. Лепить от фонаря - это интересно, но почему от фонаря? Есть еще вариант "лепить фонаря", тоже непонятный. https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/proverbs/46988/Лепить

Comment: @ Jasmin От фонаря  — наугад, от балды, на глазок, с потолка (почему так - отдельный вопрос), лепить — придумывать, привирать. Думаю, их просто соединили вместе и получилось "неумело, неубедительно вpать".

Comment: Смысл-то понятен, но откуда взялся фонарь? Меня это выражение заинтересовало как вариант: лепить горбатого/лепить от фонаря, то есть  не обязательно этого горбатого лепить по стенке, а можно просто лепить.

Answer (score 1):

К творчеству отношения не имея, фраза взята из «игроцкой» лексики профессионалов доминошного стола. Кости или камни, как известно, правильно положенные, не вызывают ни у кого возмущения, но специально или непроизвольно камень, выложенный невпопад, точно будет назван горбатым. Пик популярности домино в России был в советский период, начиная с 20-х гг. Родом из Китая, игра пришла к нам из Европы и стала несколько иной, обрусевшей, и можно предположить, что фразеологизм этот (*лепить горбатого*) изобретён любителями забить козла в те же годы.

Comment: У меня в словаре ненормативной лексики указаны два значения: (1) лгать на допросе; (2) выдавать себя за другого человека. Как-то не очень верится, что этот жаргонизм связан с домино, а неправильно поставленную фишку можно назвать горбатой. Ну почему именно горбатой? А у Вас есть ссылка на эту версию?

Comment: И первое, и второе — обман. Горбатой — потому, что  обманный ход обнаруживается раньше или позже, и неверная кость ломает игру, которая в момент теряет стройность развития и вообще смысл. Версий много, но окончательной и бесповоротной ни одна не признана.